# Facebook like button in <ul>

Tags: css, facebook, iframe

Facebook button is driving me nuts. I am trying to put all social buttons in one ul with "display: inline;" on the li elements. Here's the code:

```
        <ul id="social" class="grid_3 alpha">
            <li><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></li>
            <li><div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-count="false"></div></li>
            <li><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=en_US&href&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></li>

        </ul>
```

Here are the results:
with Safari: [image: safari]

and with Firefox: [image: firefox]

Now why aren't they showing on the same line in Safari?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the width of the `<ul>` to accommodate all 3 `<li>` tags, and `float:left` the `<li>` tags.

The critical point here is to set the defined width in the `<ul>`

Comment: Haha yes! But our answers are actually very different. Without a defined with in the UL tag, the floats will stack just like her example. I only know this because I ran into this exact issue myself :)

Comment: Thanks for float:left tip, it is working, amen!! Could you explain to me why adding it was necessary? I usually never need it when I want to do horizontal lists.

Comment: Because you put a block element (div) inside the LI tag

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Actually, the float will stack the `li` elements inline in this case, just fine. However, the real issue, which is accounting for the difference between browsers, is the `padding` and `margin`.

Comment: This is true, but the padding is included in the width in the W3 box model, so the width of the UL needs to be wide enough to accommodate all the LI tags, like my original answer. Also in the OP's example the margins and padding don't look all that different, not even by a pixel - might just be my eyes though :)

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Yes, it is included, but it's not always the same in all browsers, hence the different way the elements are stacked in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `float:left` on `li` elements. In addition, you should define/reset `margin` and `padding` for your `ul` element, because that's what is accounting for the differences between the browsers.

[Why does Firefox use other padding than Safari, Chrome and IE8?](http://doctype.com/does-firefox-use-other-padding-than-safari-chrome-ie8)

Comment: +1 for the doctype link.  First time seeing that as a resource